# How to Save user Activity in angular App?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular, web

I want to get and save user interaction with angular app,
and app interactions with the APIs the add this log to a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you can write common logic on one place for user page navigation and API call.

For page navigation, subscribe to router events. Ex.

```
constructor(router:Router) {
  router.events.subscribe(event => {
    if(event instanceof NavigationStart) {
    }
    if(event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
      // log record to file here --> 'user navigated to XYZ page.'
    }
    // NavigationCancel
    // NavigationError
    // RoutesRecognized
  }
});
```

For API calls, you can implement HTTP interceptor.

```
@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [{
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, 
    useClass: TokenInterceptorService, 
    multi: true
  }]
})
export class AppModule { }

@Injectable()
export class MyInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept( req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    // log record to file --> 'calling api {url}'
    return next.handle(req);
  }
}
```